# How to install a cer certificate on a server?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I provided my csr file and i got the signed .cer & .p7b file for a certificate.
Now how do i install it on my server?

I have a apache 2.2 server running on ubuntu 13.04

I tried adding the certificates in Apache like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/mydomain.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/mydomain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/mydomain.cer
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i restarted the apache using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Still the url is asking me certificates. How should i test whether my certificate is installed?

Please advice on this.

Regards,
Nasir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CER is the certificate in a Micrsoft-specific format. IE treats the file extension in a special way. It is NOT the chain file with the intermediates CA certificates. The chain file contains all certificates between a root CA and your server certificate. Without the chain file a browser is unable to verify the chain of trust.

Your CA should have a proper cert chain file for download somewhere on their site.